# Creating an array from variables without nil values in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

What's the most idiomatic way to create an array from several variables without `nil` values?

Given these variables:

```
a = 1
b = nil
c = 3
```

I would like to create an array `ary`:

```
ary #=> [1, 3]
```

I could use `Array#compact`:

```
ary = [a, b, c].compact
ary #=> [1, 3]
```

But putting everything in an array just to remove certain elements afterwards doesn't feel right.

Using `if` statements on the other hand produces more code:

```
ary = []
ary << a if a
ary << b if b
ary << c if c
ary #=> [1, 3]
```

Is there another or a preferred way or are there any advantages or drawbacks using either of the above?

---

PS: `false` doesn't necessarily have to be considered. The variables are either truthy (numbers / strings / arrays / hashes) or `nil`.

Comment: Is your concern that you have to loop through the values twice, or that it simply doesn't sound good to you?

Comment: @ndn it's not a technical reason. I'd use `compact` if I already had an array. But since I'm creating a new array, I think it would be cleaner not to add the `nil` values in the first place. But that is just my opinion :-)

Comment: You would have to either list them one by one in the code explicitly or create a collection and loop through it in one way or another. No matter what syntax sugar is out there, I don't think there is any other option. Would you have been happy if the method was called `non_nil_values` instead?

Comment: I guess compact is more preferable but as you are looking for other option: `[a, b, c] - [nil]`

Comment: @GaganGami that would work, but creating two intermediate arrays is even more overhead.

Comment: How many variables are there anyways?  My guess not more than handful - option with `compact` seems neat as it is more readable.

Comment: `#compact!` is IMO the best way, everybody understands it does just that at a glance, and there is good chance that beeing part of standard library it has minimal overhead. I won't bet on it, but it might be even faster than a stream of `#<<`s and `if`s.

Comment: You could extend `Array` with an alternative `push` method which skips `nil`. Then your second approach would look better.

Comment: @undur_gongor yes, that would probably reduce some visual clutter, but implementation-wise it just moves the `if` into a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, best way would be probably to use destructive `#compact!` to avoid allocating memory for second array.

Comment: You're right, `compact` would return a *new* array. On the other hand, `compact!` might return `nil`, so you have to separate the assignment from the method call, i.e. `ary = [a, b, c]; ary.compact!`

Comment: @Stefan `#compact!` will never return `nil` in this case, you have certain set of variables so array is guaranted not to be empty.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].compact!` returns `nil` and that is [expected](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-compact-21): *"Returns nil if no changes were made"*

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping for a way to somehow "skip" the `nil` values during array creation. But after thinking about this for a while, I realized that this can't be achieved because of Ruby's way to handle multiple values. There's no concept of a "list" of values, multiple values are always represented as an array.

If you assign multiple values, Ruby creates an array:

```
ary = 1, nil, 3
#=> [1, nil, 3]
```

Same for a method taking a variable number of arguments:

```
def foo(*args)
  args
end

foo(1, nil, 3)
#=> [1, nil, 3]
```

So even if I would patch `Array` with a class method `new_without_nil`, I would end up with:

```
def Array.new_without_nil(*values)
  values.compact!
  values
end
```

This just moves the code elsewhere.

#### Everything is an object

From an OO point of view, there's nothing special about `nil` - it's an object like any other. Therefore, removing `nil`'s is not different from removing `1`'s.

Using a bunch of `if` statements on the other hand is something I'm trying to avoid when writing object oriented code. I prefer sending messages to objects.

#### Regarding "advantages or drawbacks":

`[...]` with `compact` / `compact!`

- creates full array and shrinks it as needed
- short code, often fits in one line
- is easily recognized
- evaluates each item once
- faster (compiled C code)

`[...]` with `<<` and `if` statements

- creates empty array and grows it as needed
- long code, one line per item
- purpose might not be as obvious
- items can easily be commented / uncommented
- evaluates each item twice
- slower (interpreted Ruby code)

#### Verdict:

I'll use `compact`, might have been obvious.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"There's no concept of a "list" of values"*. Arrays are technically lists. Or did you mean linked lists? Does it really matter, since you will still have to use the same linear space and time either way? Also, I am curious, did you benchmark the two solutions? Intuitively, I would think that as the length of the array grows, the `if` solution would be faster (assuming there are enough `nil` values). It definitely is uglier though.

Comment: @ndn that's why I put *list* in quotes. I just wanted to point out that variable arguments in Ruby always create an additional array object. Therefore, a method `def foo(*args)` doesn't receive multiple arguments, it receives a single argument: the array. And it's pointless to create a new array from the elements, because you already have an array.

Comment: Regarding benchmarks: `compact` seems to be faster. I think that's because the `if` statements have to be interpreted one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses a hash.

With these values put in an array:

```
a = 1; b = nil; c = 3; d = nil; e = 10;
ary = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

There are two nil items in the result which would require a `compact` to remove both "nil" items.

However the same variables added to a hash:

```
a = 1; b = nil; c = 3; d = nil; e = 10;
hash = {a => nil, b => nil, c => nil, d => nil, e => nil}
```

There is just one "nil" item in the result which can easily be removed by `hash.delete(nil)`.